# how to move/configure Mysql Database to another partition?

Tags: mysql, database

The current partition of mine mysql databases is full so it denies to start.
How can i move databases to another partition without losing anything.

Edit:  I am on Ubuntu 10 Server.

Thanks

Comment: Before doing any of that do a mysql backup - just in case and move that backed up file out of the way. Always backup b4 touching the production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As root:

1. Cleanly shut down MySQL (myqsladmin shutdown)
2. Edit /etc/my.cnf and set the data-dir configuration option to the new location of your MySQL data directory.
3. Move your entire data directory to the new location, ie: mv /var/lib/mysql/* /mnt/mysql/
4. Ensure permissions are correct, chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/mysql
5. Start MySQL as usual.

Comment: Remember to do these operations as root.

Comment: You rules, works awesomely :D