# MySQL crashes running but not working

Tags: mysql5.5

Mysql is running but it not responding when using phpmyadmin when i check mysqld.log it tells:

```
[root@dc /]# tail /var/log/mysqld.log
151111  8:58:21 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as         process 27664 ...
151111  8:58:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151111  8:58:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151111  8:58:22  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
```

and when i check my disk usage i find that my disk is full

```
[root@dc ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   19G     0 100% /
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         32G  508K   32G   1% /dev
/dev/md3        1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /home
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100%            
/var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

Comment: We have lots of questions and answers about full disks - [search is your friend](http://serverfault.com/search?q=disk+full).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you didn't specify but probably want, is investigate what is taking up the space, and then remove files selectively.

I tend to do so by finding files that are over a certain size, starting big like 100mb:

```
find / -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

You probably also need to look in to logrotate and a monitoring solution like monit to ensure you get warned when it is say 85% full next time.

Edit after getting more info:

Your MySQL DB is over 17GB in size. It is on a partition of 20GB in size. So it's full.

You have an almost empty partition of 1.8 TB:

> /dev/md3        1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /home

I suggest moving (perhaps copying first) your MySQL DB files there. That's not just done with mv so look into the proper procedure before doing so.

Just like "My disk is full", the problem of moving a MySQL DB to another disk or partition has been explained many times over too:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/224/how-to-i-move-mysql-data-files-onto-different-partition

[how to move/configure Mysql Database to another partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/152549/how-to-move-configure-mysql-database-to-another-partition)

Comment: rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on `/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe

Comment: Yes it is, hence my warning. But it is in fact a valid answer to your short question. Trying to guess what you really want, I have now expanded my answer.

Comment: question edited im looking to free disk without removing mysql files from the server

Comment: The log part you posted doesn't show anything related to a full disk, just a tail isn't sufficient, but we get the picture. Your question still doesn't contain a question, but again, we get now what you mean. Just follow the two answers provided to you, and you will find which files are taking up the space. You can then figure out whether it's safe to delete those, and how to avoid them accumulating again in future.

Comment: here's the output
[root@dc /]# find / -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
find: File system loop detected; `/var/named/chroot/var/named' is part of the same file system loop as `/var/named'.
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1: 17G
/var/www/html/ie/admin/addons/installer/install/backup/general_log.txt: 359M

Comment: Your root partition is 20GB. MySQL takes 17GB. The rest of the Operating System and software is likely to take over 2GB. So your goal of freeing up space there without affecting MySQL isn't going to work. You can try to find out whether you can save 359MB by deleting or emptying that general_log.txt but that is going to buy you only a few hours or days it seems. Fact is, you need to use a bigger partition for MySQL, or offload MySQL to some external place. Your /home partition has plenty of space, you can move MySQL DB files there (in the proper way).

Comment: Yes, `rm -rf –-no-preserve-root /` would literally free all used space, but it's obviously not the question here. It's a very dangerous command to be posting, as people with the same problem who are in a hurry (and hence might not be reading things very carefully) or do not speak English as native language might be tempted to actually run it. Which would lead to unnecessary chaos.

Comment: The original question was literally "how can i remove all these used spaces?" with nothing else on offer. The correct answer is just that what I have given. Of course I had a hunch that wasn't what he wanted, forcing me to speculate, and elaborating to a perhaps more useful answer. No need to downvote a correct answer to a perhaps ill-formed question. Especially considering I have then spelled out every step along the way for him to remedy his true problem.

Comment: what u said  is true i have home directory empty how can i move my Mysql DB files to /home in safe way?

Comment: I already put the instructions in my edited answer. Please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the answer if that works for you.

Comment: it works! sure thanks a lot  i moved mysql db to /home and edited my.cf and the mysqld worked again.

Comment: @JayMcTee: The first comment by the OP clearly demonstrate why your non-serious answer `rm -rf /` is not acceptable here - people take this shit literal.

Comment: Sven, thanks for editing. Omer, thanks for following my steps and resolving it, and for accepting it as the correct answer. In future, do try to formulate a better question (which generally contains a sentence ending with a question mark) and I will then jump straight to a better answer like we ended up here. All is well that ends well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cd /
du -ks ./* | sort -n
```

to get an idea where most of space is used up.
You can then drill down to find somthing to safely delete in order to free up space.

Comment: in my server panel there's two partitions the first one is /home and the second one is root which is full. i need to free space to be able to run mysql .

Comment: What do you get from du (disk usage) ?- it will help you find some logs to delete.